# Getting and setting np.array elements in a different way

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D np.array.

```
array = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

I have a dictionary.

```
element_ids = {1: (0, 1), 2: (1, 0), 3: (0, 0), 4: (1, 1)}
```

I want to write a class that would allow me to get and set elements of an array both the ordinary way

```
>> my_array = MyArray(array, element_ids)
>> my_array[0, 1]
1
>> my_array[0, 1] = 5
>> my_array[0, 1]
5
```

and using ids from my dictionary

```
>> my_array[1, 0]
3
>> my_array.by_id(2)
3
>> my_array.by_id(2) = 7
>> my_array.by_id(2)
7
>> my_array[1, 0]
7
```

in this case i want `my_array.by_id(i)` act as if i wrote `my_array[element_ids[i]]`.
How can I do this?

I wrote a class that would allow to get elements both ways

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray:
    def __init__(self, array, element_ids):
        self.array = array
        self.element_ids = element_ids

    def by_id(self, element_id):
        indices = self.element_ids[element_id]
        return self[indices]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        i, j = key
        return self.array[i, j]


array = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
element_ids = {1: (0, 1), 2: (1, 0), 3: (0, 0), 4: (1, 1)}
my_array = MyArray(array, element_ids)
```

but it wouldn't allow me to set the elements. How can I make it work? If that's impossible, what are the best alternatives that would allow to get and set array elements in these two different ways?

Comment: Assigning to a function call is a syntax error. I don't think one can work around that.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to make by_id with square brackets?

Comment: Yes, of course. create a proxy class `By_Id` and make `by_id` a read only property of your main class that returns a `By_Id` instance. `By_Id` would implement `__get/setitem__` and forward all requests to the main class after mapping the keys

Comment: How about defining `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to handle both.  If `key` is a 2 element tuple, unpack it as you already do.  If it's a scalar or single item tuple, use the key lookup.  `numpy.lib.index_tricks.py` has some good examples of custom get/set methods.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for suggestion, but i think defining both in the same place would be confusing, so it's better to make it explicit that we use id here, and not the position in the array.

Answer (score 1):

With some help from Paul Panzer I managed to find the solution.

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray:
    def __init__(self, array, element_ids):
        self.array = array
        self.by_id = ById(self, element_ids)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        i, j = key
        return self.array[i, j]

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        i, j = key
        self.array[i, j] = item


class ById:
    def __init__(self, my_array, element_ids):
        self.my_array = my_array
        self.element_ids = element_ids

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.my_array[self.element_ids[key]]

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.my_array[self.element_ids[key]] = item
```

This works as intended with the exception of brackets instead of parentheses after `by_id`. Thanks for support.